# CCAvenue Error Code: 10001 (Payment gateway)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

i am try this package cc_avenue: ^1.0.3

but when clikc payment button then  show  error
"Error Code:         10001 Invalid Request - Encrypted request invalid/not present.

my evry url corrcet . why face this esssu please help me

```
transUrl: 
accessCode: '
amount: '100'
cancelUrl: "
currencyType:
merchantId: '
orderId: ''
redirectUrl: 
rsaKeyUrl: '
```

'm doing Payment gateway integration with CCAvenue. After selecting payment mode(Selected hdfc payment method) I'm clicking on continue button it shows the following error